# Is there a way to check NVLink compatibility between 2 different cards?

Tags: video-card, nvlink

I have tried to pair up 2 rtx 3090s for NVLink so far, but none of them fit. Either the NVLink header is different distance from the pci-e slot, or its too far from the io ports.

Is there a way to ensure that these two distances match up? I didn't find anything in the spec that indicates this property.

[image]